# Divide By Zero Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm currently encountering an issue with dividing by zero - I'm trying to implement `CASE` to just mark the divided number as "1" however, I'm still getting the error - I'm guessing I'm missing something here? Just not sure what...

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN c.PageCount IS NULL OR c.PageCount=0 THEN 1 ELSE c.PageCount END as [PageCount], 

    cast(c.PageCount / CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate)END as decimal(5,2)) as PagesPerMinute,

    CASE
       WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) >= 30 AND CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) AS FLOAT)/CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) >= 1 THEN 
             CASE WHEN CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) * 0.5 /*Half minute*/ > 45 /*minutes*/ THEN 45 ELSE CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) * 0.5 /*Half minute*/ END 
       WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) >= 60 AND CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) AS FLOAT)/CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) < 1 /* 1 minute/page */ THEN 60
       ELSE
         DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate)
    END    [MinutesPaid]


FROM 
    tbl_Charts c
    left outer join (select cd.ChartId, count(*) as CodesFound from tbl_ChartCodes cd group by cd.ChartId) cd on cd.ChartId = c.ChartId,
    tbl_WFChartEvents ev, 
    tbl_Users u,
    (select evar.ChartId, evar.ActionUserId, ar.ResultDescription, evar.ActionRemark, evar.ActionDate
    from tbl_WFChartEventActions evar, tbl_WFChartEventActionResults ar 
    where evar.EventId = 201 
    and evar.ActionResultId = ar.ResultID and evar.EventId = ar.EventID 
    and evar.ActionTypeId = ar.ActionTypeID
    and evar.EventId = 201) arr 

WHERE 
c.ChartId = ev.ChartId
and ev.EventId = 201
and ev.EventCreateUserId = u.UserId
and arr.ActionUserId = u.UserId
and arr.ChartId = c.ChartId

order by ev.EventCreateDate
```

Comment: What is your page count?  Try commenting out each column in the select until you know for sure what column causes the error.

Comment: As @Bowlturner below mentioned - I think it's the fact that PageCount in the Case statements at the bottom of the select are just taking in the c.PageCount info minus all the Case When info that I combined with the PageCount - CASE WHEN c.PageCount IS NULL OR c.PageCount=0 THEN 1 ELSE c.PageCount END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For easier readability/maintainability of division formulas, wrap every divisor with [`NULLIF(x,0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx).**

This is easier than checking for zeros with a case statement and ensuring the divisor is identical to the case predicate. Everywhere you see a `/ [...]`, make it `/ NULLIF( [...] ,0)`

instead of this:

```
cast(
  c.PageCount / CASE
                  WHEN (DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) IS NULL 
                     OR DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) = 0
                  )
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate)
                END
  as decimal(5,2)
) as PagesPerMinute,
```

do this:

```
cast(
  coalesce(
    c.PageCount / NULLIF(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate), 0)
   ,c.PageCount --Return this value if preceding is null or div_by_zero
  )
  as as decimal(5,2)
) as PagesPerMinute
```

Comment: And what is the coalesce there to ensure? (I'm just curious since I haven't used it before but according to Microsofts' T-SQL info - Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as nonnullable)

Comment: Tried adding the NULLIF on all division formulas (if you look at the last Case statement there are a few) and it gave me the following error: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

Comment: The `coalesce` substitutes an alternate return value in case the calculation is meaningless (i.e., datediff = 0, or a date is null, etc).  The basic idea is to decouple your business logic from your display logic.

Comment: `Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.` Well, `numeric(5,2)` is {-999.99 .. 999.99}.  Do you have a PageCount >= 1000?

Comment: Yep I do have a few Pagcounts that are  PageCount >= 1000

Answer (score 0):

OK, 3rd time the charm?  I thought I found the problem twice, but I think I know what's going on now.

All sql I know, you can't use an aliased column else where in the select.  By aliasing c.PageCount to [PageCount] I believe you are still using the original c.PageCount without the table alias.  To test this out, just change [PageCount] to [PageCount2].  I suspect you will get an error it doesn't recognize the column name.

This only 'appears' to work because you reused the already unique column name from the results.

What I meant was take this case and replace the [PageCount] with it.

```
CASE WHEN c.PageCount IS NULL OR c.PageCount=0 THEN 1 ELSE c.PageCount END
```

like this

```
CASE
   WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) >= 30 AND CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) AS FLOAT)/CAST(CASE WHEN c.PageCount IS NULL OR c.PageCount=0 THEN 1 ELSE c.PageCount END AS FLOAT) >= 1 THEN 
         CASE WHEN CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) * 0.5 /*Half minute*/ > 45 /*minutes*/ THEN 45 ELSE CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) * 0.5 /*Half minute*/ END 
   WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) >= 60 AND CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) AS FLOAT)/CAST(CASE WHEN c.PageCount IS NULL OR c.PageCount=0 THEN 1 ELSE c.PageCount END AS FLOAT) < 1 /* 1 minute/page */ THEN 60
   ELSE
     DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate)
END    [MinutesPaid]
```

Comment: Yep - I think that might be it - changing the whole Case When c.PageCount... to [PageCount2] and changing all the subsequent PageCounts to PageCount2 gives me an error.  So yes, I believe that it's technically taking in cPageCount minus all the case stuff.

Comment: So you'll just have to put the PageCount case everywhere you have the [PageCount] in the select clause.

Comment: Right but I believe Pagecount is giving me a 0 which causes the division by 0 - so I'm trying to figure out how to make that whole Case statement with Pagecount applicable to Case statements using Pagecount to divide.

Comment: Keeping everything the same - and just adding in your suggestion gives me the following error: "Arithmetic overflow error converting into to data type numeric" - its a similar error I got with @Anon's query

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this `case` statement:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) >= 30 AND
          CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) AS FLOAT)/CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) >= 1
     THEN (CASE WHEN CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) * 0.5 /*Half minute*/ > 45 /*minutes*/
                THEN 45 ELSE CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) * 0.5 /*Half minute*/
           END)
     WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) >= 60 AND CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) AS FLOAT)/CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) < 1 /* 1 minute/page */
     THEN 60
     ELSE DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate)
END AS [MinutesPaid]
```

The first `when` statement has a divisision.  Just rephrase this as:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) >= 30 AND
          CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) > 0 AND
          CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) AS FLOAT) >= CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT)
     THEN (CASE WHEN CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) * 0.5 /*Half minute*/ > 45 /*minutes*/
                THEN 45 ELSE CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) * 0.5 /*Half minute*/
           END)
     WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) >= 60 AND CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate) AS FLOAT)/CAST([PageCount] AS FLOAT) < 1 /* 1 minute/page */
     THEN 60
     ELSE DATEDIFF(mi, ev.EventCreateDate, ev.EventCompletionDate)
END AS [MinutesPaid]
```

I removed the division with a simple comparison *and* guarantee the value is not 0.

Comment: Keeping everything from the original query and just adding in your suggestion still gives me a "Divide by Zero error encountered"